# Evaluate $\sum \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt n).$$

so for this, I multiplied by the conjugate $\sqrt {n+1}+ \sqrt n$ and then got limit $1/(n+1-n^2)$ however says it converges to zero?

Comment: Having been a user here for close to five years, surely you're aware that some sort of formatting is necessary to make the question reasonably readable.

Comment: Plus you must have mis-read the problem, because the sum you presented diverges.

Comment: T. Bongers, surprising, havent been a user here for 5 years despite having my account here. I'm a different user

Comment: @mary Apparently the first question that was asked on your account was in April 2011, which is well over four years ago.... But regardless of your account age, please put a little effort into properly using Mathjax to make this readable.

Comment: I need help, T. bongers could you help me out this time please? Trying to learn the syntax now

Comment: @mary : Latex is not difficult. click 'edit' to see what I've done. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more.

Comment: Easiest: Look at partial sums, the sum to $m$ is $\sqrt{m+1}-1$. Your way: Your rationalizing the numerator should lead to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$. Conclude that the sum diverges, by comparison with a suitable $p$-series.

Comment: I've looked at some p-tests however the way I have it, could you put it in a formal answer?

Comment: See also: 
[Does this series diverge: $(\sqrt 2-\sqrt 1)+(\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2)+(\sqrt 4-\sqrt 3)+(\sqrt 5-\sqrt 4)+\dots$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/962301) and 
[Verify if $\sum(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$ is convergent or divergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2311433)

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to see that the sum does not converge.

Imagine you add only the first $k$ terms of the series. You got

$$
(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1})+(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})+(\sqrt{4}-\sqrt{3})+\cdots+(\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1})+(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})
$$

Now you can perform the addition, and you see that all the terms, apart the first ($-\sqrt{1}$) and the very last $\sqrt{k+1}$ cancel out.

So the sum of the first $k$ terms of the series is just $\sqrt{k+1}-1$, thus the series cannot converge.

This technique of [telescoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) is useful when your series can be put in the form
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(f(i+1)-f(i)) 
$$
or something similar.

Your approach of multiplying by the conjugate can be done, but you did in the wrong way.

You should multiply and divide for the same quantity, otherwise you are changing the value of the terms of the serie!

Here

$$
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{1}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
$$

So you have to compute 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
$$

Again it is easy to see that this cannot converge because
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}>\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}>\frac{1}{n}
$$
for $n>4$, because for $n>4$ we have $n>2\sqrt{n+1}$. And I assume you know that the series $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ does not converge.

Comment: This is good however doesn't directly answer what I'm looking for. Could you please incorporate the question in it?